# How to place Admob Native Advanced Ads in recycler view android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, android-adapter, native-ads

I want to place the admob native advanced ads in every 3 position of my recycler view in android app.

I would like to use the template provided by Admob.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-native-templates

Here is XML code implementation of native ads

```
<com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
android:id="@+id/my_template"
<!-- this attribute determines which template is used. The other option is
@layout/gnt_medium_template_view -->
app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is Java code implementation of Admob

```
   MobileAds.initialize(this, "[_app-id_]");
   AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "[_ad-unit-id_]")
 .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
      NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
          NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(background).build();

      TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
      template.setStyles(styles);
      template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);

    }
 })
 .build();

  adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
 }
```

**RecyclerView Adapter Class**:

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private Context mContext;
private List<ArticleJson> articleList;
String titleoflist;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle,txtDesc,txtStatus,txtColor,txtAuthor;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private ArticleJson m_articleJson;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        txtTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.texViewArticleTitle)
        linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.article_linearlayout);
    }

    public void bindView(final ArticleJson articleJson){
        m_articleJson = articleJson;
        txtTitle.setText(articleJson.getmTitle());
        txtAuthor.setText(titleoflist);
    }
}

public ArticleAdapter(Context mContext, List<ArticleJson> articleList,String titleoflist) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.articleList = articleList;
    this.titleoflist = titleoflist;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
          .inflate(R.layout.list_item_article, parent, false);
   return new ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
final ArticleJson articleJson = articleList.get(position);
    holder.bindView(articleJson);
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      //Toast
    }
});
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return articleList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: There is no question, so no one can help

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First, you need to create the Ads container `item_ads.xml` folder**

```
<com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
    android:id="@+id/my_template"
    <!-- this attribute determines which template is used. The other option is
    @layout/gnt_medium_template_view -->
    app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Second, your recyclerview adapter must extends the following**

```
 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

Now you need to **override** 4 methods

`public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder()`

`public void onBindViewHolder()`

`public int getItemCount()`

`public int getItemViewType()`

In the getItemViwType() method, We will define two possibilities

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {     
    if (AD_LOGIC_CONDITION)) {
        return AD_TYPE;
    } else{  
        return CONTENT_TYPE; ///do not forget to initialize any of AD_TYPE and CONTENT_TYPE
    }
}
```

then we will create two view holders, one for your content and second for your Ads
I assume that you know how to create your view holder so I will just explain the AD View holder

```
class adViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TemplateView Adtemplate;

        public adViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Adtemplate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_template);
        }
```

Now we return to the `onCreateViewHolder()` method

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
            adViewHolder madViewHolder = new adViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_ads, null, false));
            return madViewHolder;
        } else{
            YourViewHolder mYourViewHolder = new YourViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, null, false));
            return mYourViewHolder;
        }
}
```

now we go to the `onBindViewHolder()` method

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_CONTENT) {
                ///your data 
// AN EXAMPLE
                ((YourViewHolder) holder).textview.setText(data.getmtext());
                ((YourViewHolder) holder).Img.setImageResource(data.getmImg());
                ((YourViewHolder) holder).title.setText(data.getmName());
            } else if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_AD){
    
                final AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                        .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                                // Show the ad.
                                NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                        NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
    
                                TemplateView template = ((adViewHolder) holder).Adtemplate;
                                template.setStyles(styles);
                                template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);
    
                            }
                        })
                        .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                                // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                            }
                        })
                        .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                                // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                                // used here to specify individual options settings.
                                .build())
                        .build();
                adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    
    
            }
```

Comment: Would you mind to help me this https://stackoverflow.com/q/63335533/4499768

Comment: It works, but its not a nice approach. Ads does not load until the user scroll. You have scroll back up in order to see an ad. Therefore it is recommended to load ad with `List<UnifiedNativeAd>`.

Comment: This way every AD_LOGIC_CONDITION hides a TYPE_CONTENT in favor of an TYPE_AD.

Answer (score 0):

in Your article list, fill every third entry with "null" values (or "Ad" String value if You want).

in Your Adapter set for list entries with "null" values content_type = "AD_TYPE":

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {     
        if (yourList.get(position).getArticle().equals("null")) {
            ADPosition = position;
            return AD_TYPE;
        }
        return CONTENT_TYPE;
    }
```

and in Your ViewHolderClass set AD_Layout for AD_TYPE Entries and normal layout for CONTENT_TYPE entries.

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
if (viewType == CONTENT_TYPE) {
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.normalLayoutRecyclerView,prent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView)
}
if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.ad_layout, parent, false);
}

return new MyViewHolder(itemView)
```

}

Hope that helps.

GGK

Comment: Thanks I understand the concept but i don't understand the code. because i didn't find native ads template implementation in it. Also getItemViewType look confusing!!!