# Why Native Advanced ads removed the item from recycler view android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, android-adapter, unifiednativeadview

I am using this code in my adapter

[How to place Admob Native Advanced Ads in recycler view android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670307/how-to-place-admob-native-advanced-ads-in-recycler-view-android)

This problem occur

[image]

But i want result like this

[image]

Addition to my code, I am using this formula to place the item in recycler view.

```
    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position!=0 && position%4 == 0) {

        return AD_TYPE;
    }
        return CONTENT_TYPE;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mlistItems.size();
}
```

Complete adapter code

```
public class CenterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private RecyclerItemClickListener listener;
private List<list_item_center> mlistItems;
private Context mcontext;
private static final int AD_TYPE = 2;
private static final int CONTENT_TYPE = 1;

public CenterAdapter(List<list_item_center> listItems, Context context, RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
    mlistItems = listItems;
    mcontext = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position != 0 && position % 4 == 0) {
        return AD_TYPE;
    }
    return CONTENT_TYPE;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mlistItems.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `getItemCount()` you are still returning the size of same `ArrayList`. Thats why the item gets override by the Ads `layoutType`.
A better way to do this is to insert the Ad Item in the list before hand With condition `position!=0 && position%4 == 0` .

This way you do not have to manage or calculate the item position in list inside `onBindViewHolder` . Also you do not have to calculate the `itemCount` inside `getItemCount()`.

Comment: It gives me error    
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mlistItems.size();
        }
        
        if (position!=0 && position%4 == 0) {

            return AD_TYPE;
        }
            return CONTENT_TYPE;

    } Would be great you can share the example here

Comment: is it complete now @ADM? If we remove everything from onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder. How it will fetch the id ads

Comment: @RohitKumarSehrawat [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38027391/4168607) is way i am talking about. And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40608363/4168607) is the other way where you need to calculate the indexes.

Comment: It look too confusing to me.